# How can I change text content inside div when hovered over

Tags: jquery, html, css, text

I have a div that is pretty small with black font, when you hover over it the div grows in size to a background of red and ideally the font changes to white and displays different text.  As of right now, I have black font saying "hover me" and when you scroll of it the div grows, bgcolor changes red and white font is displayed inside of it.  However, the black hover me is still in the div and the white font is actually already on the page, it just becomes visible with the div grows in size and changes red giving the white font a background that can display it.

How can I make my div change its font color and more importantly change the text contents inside of it when I hover it?

below is the code I'm using, I can update the site to a url if needed for further exploration

//html

```
     <section class="box content">
    <div id="tOne"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Title One</h2>
      <p>This is where text goes </p>
            <div class="someContent">
                <p>hover me</p>
                <p id="pWhite"><br>Lets check the overview of this content</p>
            </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

//css

```
section.box h2 {
padding-top: 0;
margin: -7px 0;
color: #D11010;
font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 30px;
}

section.box p {
padding-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 20px;
color: black;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: cursive;
font-weight: 300;
}

section.box p:last-child {
margin-bottom: 300px;
}

section.box.content {
padding-top: 0;
padding-left: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
height: 500px;
}
.someContent {
width: 30%;
margin-left: 100px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 10px;
text-align: left;
padding: 0px;
color: black;
height: 60px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

}

.highLight {
background: rgba(209, 16, 16, 1);
border: 2px solid black;
overflow: hidden;
color: white;
width: 80%;
height: 400px;
}
```

//jQuery for the hover effect

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".someContent").hover( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
}
, function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
});
})
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: CSS and transition could do this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbvxVg , is it what you look for ?

Comment: I think that is exactly what I'm looking for.  How the white text expands out when you hover over the box, but is not viewable before

Comment: is that only achievable with using pure CSS, I wanted to use the jQuery hover for practice.

Answer (score 2):

You actually doesn't need the jQuery code at all, you can just use the `:hover` pseudo-class in CSS.

Put some classes on the text inside the element, so that you can target them easily from the CSS:

```
<p class="initial">hover me</p>
<p class="hovered">Lets check the overview of this content</p>
```

Now you can hide the longer text from start, and hide the inital text and show the longer text when the element is hovered:

```
.someContent .hovered { display: none; }
.someContent:hover .hovered { display: block; }
.someContent:hover .initial { display: none; }
```

Instead of the `.highLight` class, use the `:hover` class to change the appearence of the element when hovered:

```
.someContent:hover {
  ... the CSS from the .highLight rule
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/60mtzqa4/

Answer (score 1):

Its easy using JQuery, just use .html.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".someContent").hover( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
    $(this).html("Your new content here");
}
, function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
    $(this).html("Your original content here if you want it to change back");
});
})
```

Comment: You can delete the new text from your HTML - just include your default start text in the HTML, then replace and restore the text with jquery.

Comment: this seems to just destroy the functionality of the hover mechanic, it does change the content text though to the "your new content here"

Answer (score 1):

This issue is actually about [css specificity](http://specificity.keegan.st/).

If you add the following css, it'll fix the issue ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/c6r0qarv/))

```
.highLight p:first-child {
    display: none;
}
section.box .highLight p {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: this seems to bring the white next up into the hover created div very nicely, but the white text is still viewable on the page before you hover into he box.

Answer (score 1):

You could able do the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <style>
        .somecontent{
          color: black;
        }
        #pWhite{
          display: none;
          color: white;
          background: red;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <section class="box content">
        <div id="tOne"></div>
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Title One</h2>
          <p>This is where text goes </p>
                <div class="someContent">
                    <p>hover me</p>
                    <p id="pWhite"><br>Lets check the overview of this content</p>
                </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".someContent").hover(function(){
            $(".someContent p").css("display", "none");
            $("#pWhite").css("display", "block");
          },function(){
            $(".someContent p").css("display", "block");
            $("#pWhite").css("display", "none");
            
          });
        });
          
        
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Checkout this DEMO: http://jsbin.com/fuqumevuqu/1/